# Calling WebService In Cross Domain

Tags: c#, web-services, web

I want to call webservice from domain A with the C# code in Domain B. I have tried to add web reference with URL of that web service but it gives error like

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:15666/MailBox/'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:15666
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:15666/MailBox/$metadata'.
Unable to connect to the
```

I am having so many issues because of cross domains. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I don't believe C# is limited by cross-domain request. Actually that should be how you handle cross-domain request by sending it to your backend to fetch the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi finally I get answer for my question ,This is not problem with crossdomain but I get problems because I didn't create disco file or WSDL file for my webservice so I get error for metadata.I run my webservice locally get WSDL file from there and create new WSDL file for my WEB SERVICE and boom... problem solved .Thanks for all your help...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have requested the web service on localhost, this isn't a cross-domain issue. I suspect that you need to update your reference to point to a web service on a different machine.

Comment: Actually My Webservice and c# code that calling that webservice are in different domains so I think that is because of different domain or some permission issue.I can call webservice from same machine without any problem

Comment: Yes, but your error message is explicitly referencing the local machine. I think that when you executed the code that generated the exception, you weren't pointing at the other machine.

Comment: I think You are right ,May be I typed wrong URL ,I will try in that direction

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (at least the exception you pasted) has nothing to do with calling web services on another domain. It indicates that your machine (localhost) has port `15666` closed and hence you receive the `actively refused it` error message. You are either not running your web service on that port or your windows firewall is blocking the connection, although this is very unlikely since firewalls usually accept connections from localhost.

You can always check this sort of thing by telneting to localhost on the particular port you are interested in or by using nmap to scan your own ports.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a file (clientaccesspolicy.xml) and put it into the wwwroot directory or the main directory of your webservice.

Content of the file should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

You can read more about that at [To use a clientaccesspolicy.xml file to allow cross-domain access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I try this clientaccesspolicy.xml file.But I think it will be just for silverlight ,In my case it doesn't give any help.Any way thank you